# web2py create account while login

Tags: web2py

Currently,I am making web application using web2py.

What I would like to do is creating account while a user is login already.

I know that in "auth()", there is "http://.../[app]/default/user/register".

If an user do is not login, this "register" works as "sign up." 
However, if an user is already login, "register" works as "change account information."

Is there a way I can maintain "register" as "sign up" even if I am already login ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to use `auth.register()` in this case, as that is intended for users who are signing up themselves. Instead, you can try something like this (in a controller file):

```
def add_user():
    form = SQLFORM(db.auth_user,
                   fields=['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password'])
    if form.validate():
        user = auth.get_or_create_user(form.vars, login=False, get=False)
        response.flash = 'User %s created' % user.id if user else 'User already exists'
    return dict(form=form)
```

Unlike `.process()`, by default, the `.validate()` method does not insert any data in the database. In this case, we instead do the insert via `auth.get_or_create_user()`. We must set `login=False` so the login will not be switched to the new account, and we set `get=False` so `None` will be returned in case the user already exists (allowing a special error message to be displayed in that case).

Comment: Thank you for answer. It works! However, I totally forgot to add one more thing in the question... Is there anyway I can obtain the the id. Since "login=False, "auth.user.id" will give me the logged one.. I would like to know the id of account that is created by "auth.get_or_create_user(form.vars, login=False, get=False)". Thank you so much

Comment: The `user` variable holds the new user record, so the id is `user.id` (I edited the answer to include it in the flash message).